# How do I access a SilverLight UserControl's property in my codebehind?

Tags: asp.net, silverlight

I just started learning  silverlight by creating a silverlight application in Visual Web Developer 2008.

I have a public property defined in the user control. How do I access this property value in the aspx codebehind page? Please help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Initialize the property when the page loads? Read it when it changes? Depending on what you're trying to do, you might need some JavaScript, so more details would help us answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a property on the `UserControl` from aspx code-behind.  Aspx code-behind executes on the server where as the Silverlight `UserControl` runs on the client.

If you want your aspx code-behind to supply data to the Silverlight application you use the "initParams" parameter for the object tag:-

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/SilverlightApplication1.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.50303.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
                  <param name="initParams" id="initParams" runat="server" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.50303.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

The above is the default object tag configuration from the test aspx page created to host the silverlight app.  However there is one difference, the `<param name="initParams"` element has been added and marked as a server side control.

Now server-side aspx code-behind can modify the value of this param element:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    initParams.Attributes["value"] = "input=Hello";
}
```

A usercontrol that wants to discover the values specified in this way can do so with code like this:-

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SomeTextBox.Text = App.Current.Host.InitParams["input"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean but you can give your UserControl in the XAML side a name with: x:Name="myControl" next you can use this.myControl.MyProperty.